# How to send body data from $.ajax in POST request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post

I am working in a web client and I would like to send a post request using $.ajax from jquery. I am able to send a request as expected using POSTMAN client as I show in the following picture:

[image: Postman request]

When I try to do it from jquery like this:

```
$.ajax({
        url: urlRequest,
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        headers:{
            "Authorization": "Basic " + btoa(username + ":" + password)
        },
        data:{                
            "summary":"Creating a new ticket",
            "company":{
                "id": 201
            }                
        },
        success: function (results) {
            alert('Ticket ' + results.id + ' successfully created');
        },
        error: function (x, y, z) {
            alert('Network error has occurred. Please try again!');
        }
    });
```

I have a "400 Bad Request" response from the server. I have the same data in both headers (POSTMAN and JQUERY) and I do not have any problem with authorization. It seems like I am not sending the data as expected.

How should I have to send the data from body in the $.ajax function?. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `data` would of course have to contain json. Currently it contains an object.

Comment: @KevinB, I have tried using JSON.stringify before. I was not including dataType: 'json'. Thank you very much. It is working now.